# How do I resolve the error "No matching distribution found for pywin32"?

Tags: python, pycharm, pywin32

I am trying to install pywin32 and also tried installing pypiwin32 but everytime it throws an error message stating :

```
Collecting pywin32
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

I am trying to install this package on pycharm using Tool > External Tools > Pydl UI > Install.
I even tried Installing it via python interpreter.

Comment: can you show your attempt from the python interpreter too?

Comment: ```Collecting pywin32 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248D3CC7358>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pywin32/ No matching distribution found for pywin32 ``` Similar error occurs in case of pypiwin32

Comment: erm you need an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check interpreter (File/Settings/Project:xxx/Project Interpreter), and make sure that's the one you are adding libraries to. Or just create an empty project and select the interpreter you are updating, and it should work out.